# Chocolate choux pastry

Tags: pastry, puff-pastry

I've been trying to get a working recipe for chocolate choux pastry.This basic recipe is aproximate:

- 80​g​ all purpose flour
- 18g cocoa powder
- 65g butter
- 28g sugar
- 135g liquid (70g milk; 60g water)
- 150g eggs

I find that they don't rise really. They come out more like thick cookies. **The recipe cautions** that the cocoa is heavy and they won't rise as much - but this is pretty extreme.

My recipes for normal flavored ones come out fine.

Also, **do you recommend cooking the flour and chocolate together in the sauce pan?** I was thinking instead of mixing the chocolate in after at the time I'm mixing in the eggs...

Comment: Welcome! This is at its core a very interesting question and I am looking forward to the community‘s suggestions. Please note that recipe requests are off topic (so I have removed this part), asking for the principles however is perfectly fine. The [tour] and the [help] will get you started.

Comment: @M.K reminder: recipe requests are explicitly off topic. The question is fine otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen recipes with and without milk, but the ingredients seem fine (150g eggs means 3 eggs?).

The importance of this recipe is the **methodology**:

1. Boil the mix liquid (or water) with butter, and **reduce to simmer in a saucepan**.
2. Sift cocoa and flour and sugar, and add it to the saucepan, **combining it until it forms a dough that comes away from the sides**. Then put away from fire and in a bowl.
3. Mix the eggs somewhere, and add it to the dough in 4 times, mixing.

The final batter should be dense but remind you to **the middle point of a chocolate ganache and a chocolate frosting**. Now with a piping bag, add the batter and make the shapes (you can make a ball) in a tray laying cooking paper, and bake! Depending on the ingredients, I'd say generically, in pre-heated 200C, 30 mins.